# JSON error message

Tags: java, json

i wrote this JSON code

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputJson= "{" +"\"contexts\" : {  "+ "{ " + "\"times\" : { " + "{  " + "\"end\":17, " + "\"begin\" : 9 " +  "}" + "}," +    "\"contextname\":\"OFFICE_HOURS\" " +   "}," + "{ " + "\"days\": { " + "\"MON\", " +    "\"TUE\", " + "\"WED\" , " + "\"THU\", " +  "\"FRI\" " +    "} , " + "\"contextname\" : \"WORKDAYS\" " +    "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);

        try {

            MainParser mp= mapper.readValue(inputJson, MainParser.class);

            System.out.println(mp.getContextname());
        }
```

but i found this error in the console box

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7cf10a6f; line: 1, column: 19]
```

i need help please

Comment: You have attempted to construct a JSON string using concatenation, and when you attempted to use it you got an error message that tells you there is a syntax error, and tells you exactly where in the string it is.  The next step is to output the constructed string (e.g. using println or by inspecting it with a debugger), and search for the syntax error.

Comment: What did you expect `{"contexts" : {  { ` to do?

Comment: Why all the string concatenation?

Comment: But why have you divided the json and then concatenated it with '+'?
If you remove all the concatenation you will see that the json is incorrectly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

When formatted your JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "contexts": {
    {
      "times": {
        {
          "end": 17,
          "begin": 9
        }
      },
      "contextname": "OFFICE_HOURS"
    },
    {
      "days": {
        "MON",
        "TUE",
        "WED",
        "THU",
        "FRI"
      },
      "contextname": "WORKDAYS"
    }
```

This is not valid, for multiple reasons.

You could make it valid by replacing the content of "contexts" with an array and wrapping the days in an array, and removing some extra curly brackets.

```
{
  "contexts": [
    {
      "times": {
        "end": 17,
        "begin": 9
      },
      "contextname": "OFFICE_HOURS"
    },
    {
      "days": [
        "MON",
        "TUE",
        "WED",
        "THU",
        "FRI"
      ],
      "contextname": "WORKDAYS"
    }
  ]
}
```

A better way may be to use the "contextname" values as keys and simplifying the whole JSON.

```
{
  "OFFICE_HOURS": {
    "end": 17,
    "begin": 9
  },
  "WORKDAYS": [
    "MON",
    "TUE",
    "WED",
    "THU",
    "FRI"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is Json string as per code.  It is not in correct json format.

{"contexts" : {  { "times" : { {  "end":17, "begin" : 9 }},"contextname":"OFFICE_HOURS" },{ "days": { "MON", "TUE", "WED" , "THU", "FRI" } , "contextname" : "WORKDAYS" }

Try to fix json string format and run the code again.